# AAD application with 'Single Page Application' as platform PowerShell script

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I need to create an azure active directory (AAD) application. Here is the command I use:

```
$uiApp = New-AzADApplication    -DisplayName $uiAppDisplayName `
                                            -AvailableToOtherTenants $false `
                                            -ReplyUrls $replyUrls `
                                            -RequiredResourceAccess $requiredResourceAccess
```

How do I update the script to create an application with 'Single Page Application' as platform?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create an application with **'Single Page Application'** as platform, you need to add `-SPARedirectUri $uri` to your existing script.

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got below results:***

I used below command to create application with **'Single Page Application'** as platform like this:

```
Connect-AzAccount -tenant <tenantID>
$uiAppDisplayName = "SriGraphApp"
$uri = "http://localhost:3000"
$uiApp = New-AzADApplication    -DisplayName $uiAppDisplayName `
                                -AvailableToOtherTenants $false `
                                -SPARedirectUri $uri
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I checked the same in Portal, `SriGraphApp` with **'Single Page Application'** as platform created sucessfully as below:

[image]